# GNUplot batch plotting producing empty plot files

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to plot approximately 81 3d plot files with separate output files. 
I want to be able to automate the process so that I do not have to manually print all 81 files.

I used the code:

```
do for [ii=1:81] {
  set output 'filename'.ii.'.png'
  splot 'filename'.ii.'.dat' }
```

Apart from the output png files, an output file opens automatically labelled "Deltaii.dat". This automatic output file shows a plot. However, when I open the individual png files they are all blank with a size of 0 KB.
Individually plotting the files produces normal 3d plots.

How do I perform the batchplot process to ensure the output shows up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a line

```
set terminal png
```

at the start of the commands.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.